# how to solve this (selecting intervals)

Tags: algorithm, intervals

I've given some intervals `I = {I(1), I(2), ..., I(m)}` for `I(i) = [a_i, b_i] (1<=a_i<=b_i<=n)`. You may suppose that intervals cover each other(sorry i'm poor in english), so there's no intervals such as `{[1,5], [3,6]}, {[2,5], [5,7]}`. And `{[1,1], [2,2], ..., [n,n]}` must be included in I.

Let's suppose `C(i) = b_i - a_i + 1`.

I want to find `{I(c_1), I(c_2), ..., I(c_k)}` that are non overlapped by each other, and `C(c_1) + C(c_2) + ... + C(c_k) = T. (1 <= T <= n)`.

I could find `O(n*T)` DP solution using Subset Sum problem, and I think it's NP, but I'm not sure. Can I optimize more than `O(n*T)`?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Could you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: Finding if there is a subset of intervals such that `C(d_1) + C(d_2) + ... + C(d_k)` is NP-Hard alone (Subset Sum Problem), and the general approach to solve it is using `O(mT)` DP solution, an exponential brute force

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is reduceable from the [Subset Sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) (Given a set of numbers and a target number, find out if there is a subset that sums to this target) with a simple [reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction):

Given an instance of subset-sum: `S={c_1,c_2,..,c_n},T` - create an instance of this problem by creating `n` non overlapping intervals, interval i, with `c_i` points (easy to do by ascending order). The same `T` remains.

Now, the answer to the subset-sum problem is true if and only if there is a subset of intervals that sums to `T`. It is basically the same problem, since all intervals do not overlap each other by definition of the problem.

From this we can conclude - your problem is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard).

Moreover, if we could solve the problem better then `O(T*n)`, we could use the same approach to solve the subset sum problem better then `O(T*n)`<sup>1,2</sup>. 

However, AFAIK, best pseudo polynomial solution to subset sum is `O(T*n)`, so if you have such solution - stick with it.

---

(1) Converting the problem is `O(n)`

(2) This claim is true for this specific reduction alone, and NOT for the general case of polynomial reductions.

Comment: I added some terms, can you check it's also NP? I'm not sure about it.

Comment: @LovePaper: Do you mean NP-Hard? Or NP? (Can be solved polynomially in  non deterministic turing machine)? I already showed it is NP-Hard, I need to think for a minute if it is in NP, but my gut says it is.